# How do I can get back the value of these table cells?

Tags: javascript, html, async-await

I got this function for a CRUD to receive some data and charge it to the html:

```js
async function loaded() {
  let data = await getRequest('http://localhost/ALMACEN/Backend/get.php');

  document.getElementById("imagen").innerHTML =
    '<img src="Front-End/imagenes/' + data.data[0].prod_img + '" width="50%"; height= "auto";>';

  for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    var table = document.getElementById("employeeList").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
    cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = data.data[i].prod_nombre;
    cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = data.data[i].prod_precio;
    cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = data.data[i].prod_cantidad;
    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    cell4.innerHTML = `<a href="#" class="opis" style="background-color: #3ebd49;">&#129089</a>
                       <a href="#" class="opis" style="background-color: #f57c0a;">&#129087</a>
                       <a href="#" onclick="eliminar(this)" class="opis" style="background-color: #A50202;">Borrar</a>`;
  }

}
```

I wanna get back the values to make the Delete button work, what can I do?

Comment: try to add unique id for every row and cells , when added the id you can easily access to elements .

Answer (score 0):

Add the key fields to data attributes on the button for easy access:

```
<a href="#" class="delete-button" data-id="12">Borrar</a>`;
```

Then in JS:

```
$(".delete-button").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
});
```

If you're generating the elements dynamically, you might need to bind the click event to the document instead of the button.

You can use any and multiple data attributes: data-uid, data-name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can use this

```
$('#employeeList').on('click', '.opis', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fila=$(this).closest('tr');
    var name= fila.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    alert("name: "+name);
    $("#name").html(name);
})
```